# Apply function with Switch to a vector

Tags: r

I'm attempting to apply the following function to a vector, using the apply family (`sapply` in this case):

```
get_dates <- function(text, pattern, pattern_list){

  text <- str_to_lower(text)

  index <- switch (pattern,
    pattern_1 = 1,
    pattern_2 = 2,
    pattern_3 = 3,
    pattern_4 = 4,
    pattern_5 = 5,
    pattern_7 = 6,
    pattern_8 = 7
  )

  regex_pattern = pattern_list[index]

  dates <- str_extract(text, regex_pattern)

  return(dates)
}
```

The arguments, *text*, *pattern*, and *pattern_list* descriptions are below:

- text <- character vector taken from a data frame
- pattern <- character vector of the same length as text, taken from same data frame as text
- pattern_list <- vector of seven different regex patterns to be applied to text depending on the value of pattern

The solution I've tried is below, just using the first two elements of my text and pattern vector.

```
text <- c("FEB-MAY14", "JUN-AUG14")
pattern <- c("pattern_8", "pattern_8")

 pattern_list <- c(full_pattern_1,
             full_pattern_2,
             full_pattern_3,
             full_pattern_4,
             full_pattern_5,
             full_pattern_7,
             full_pattern_8)
```

where the elements of pattern list are below:

```
 [1] "\\d{2}\\s?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\\s?  \\d{2}\\s?\\-\\s?\\d{2}\\s?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\\s?\\d{2}"                                                                                                                                                                     
 [2] "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s?\\d{4}\\s?\\-\\s?(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s?\\d{2}\\,?\\s?\\d{4}"                                                                                               
 [3] "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s?\\-\\s?(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s?\\d{2}\\,\\s?\\d{4}"                                                                                                          
 [4] "\\d{2}\\s?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\\s?\\d{4}\\s?\\-\\s?\\d{2}\\s?(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\\s?\\d{4}"                                                                                                                                                                     
 [5] "(jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\\s?\\d{4}\\s?\\-\\s?(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s?\\d{1,2}\\,\\s?\\d{4}"                                                                                                                                    
 [6] "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s?\\d{1,2}\\,\\s?\\d{4}\\s?\\-\\s?(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december)\\s?\\d{2}\\,\\s?\\d{4}"                                                                                 
 [7] "(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)\\s?\\-?(\\d{2,4})?\\-?\\s?(january|february|march|april|may|june|july|august|september|october|november|december|jan|feb|mar|apr|may|jun|jul|aug|sep|oct|nov|dec)?\\s*\\-*\\d{2,4}"

daaa <- sapply(text, 
                function(x, y, z) get_dates(x, y, z), 
                y = pattern, 
                z = pattern_list)
```

However, I get the following error when I use `apply`:

```
Error in switch(pattern, pattern_1 = 1, pattern_2 = 2, pattern_3 = 3,  : 
EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

which doesn't make sense to me; I thought the apply family would loop through taking each element at time as it applies the function. I've used a `for-loop` to manually go through the vectors and that worked as expected:

```
daaa <- c()
for(i in 1:2){
daaa[i] <- get_dates(text[i],
                   pattern[i],
                   pattern_list)
}
```

I've left out the nature of the actual regex patterns and the text contents because that is not the problem, at least how I see it now. If that is needed I can come up with a contrived example of the inputs, but right now the problem I'm having is with applying my function and `switch` seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: You need to provide sample data so that this error can be reproduced.

Comment: In your `sapply` call "pattern" has `length > 1` as you are passing the whole vector "sales_2$pattern[1:2]" in each iteration over "sales_2$Memo.Description[1:2]"

Comment: @nrussell I've added data

Comment: @alexis_laz I get that, but I thought sapply was an abstracted loop, thus treating each element one at a time, rather than considering the entire vector.

Comment: @arvi1000, I get that, but maybe I misunderstood how `sapply` works. My understanding was if I passed an entire vector, it would use one element at a time, just like a `for` loop.

Comment: sapply treats each element of the thing to which you are applying a function one at a time (here, `text`), but that doesn't apply to arguments in the function you are applying (like `pattern`)

Comment: @arvi1000 that makes sense now; but is there a solution not using a `for` loop?

Comment: The problem is that `sapply` only passes a single value and you are using a function that accepts three arguments with no default values for arguments 2 and 3. The value would get matched to x but then y and z are value-less. If there were the same number of values in each of `text, pattern, pattern_list` then you could use `mapply`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sapply` and `for` loop constructions don't match, so it makes sense the results aren't the same. In the `for` loop, the i-th result gets `pattern[i]` as the 2nd arg. In the `sapply` version, you pass the whole vector `pattern`

`sapply` treats each element of the thing to which you are applying a function one at a time (here, `text`), but that doesn't apply to arguments in the function you are applying (like `pattern`)

If you want to iterate through multiple objects, try `apply`ing a function to an iteration vector:

```
sapply(1:12, function(i) get_dates(text[i], pattern[i], pattern_list))
```

The use of `switch` is not related, and there's no issue using `switch` with `sapply`, e.g.:

```
my_fun <- function(x) switch(x, a='alpha', b='beta')
sapply(c('a', 'b', 'b'), my_fun)

#      a       b       b 
# "alpha"  "beta"  "beta"
```

Comment: I'm a little rusty on my `R`, but `sapply(1:12, function(i) get_dates(text[i], pattern[i], pattern_list))` is definitely what I was thinking about.

Comment: I used `sapply(1:2, 
               function(i, y, x, z) get_dates(x[i], y[i], z), 
               x = text,
               y = pattern,
               z = pattern_list)`